# Send 24/96 pcm music from an rpi3b+ to a zero one

Tags: audio-playback, i2s, usb-audio

As my title says, I'd like to send audio from an rpi3b+ to another one.
Preferably a zero one via a GPIO connection.

My target is to have a dedicated device to only manage an USB DAC. 
Ideally an Rpi Zero, because I want the smallest system footprint. (Compiled from minimal scratch, a kernel RT with minimal selected modules etc...)

I've tried to find documentation for

- Rpi3 -> PCM -> Rpi Zero (Analog :( )
- Rpi3 -> i2s -> Rpi Zero
- Rpi3 -> SPI -> Rpi Zero
- Rpi3 -> USB gadget  -> Rpi Zero (Zero have only one port, and RPi can't manage master and slaves gadgets on the same board because only one controller)
- Rpi3 -> Ethernet-> Rpi Zero (Heavy system footprint to manage drivers, connections and so on)

And to select a way to transfer audio stream

- Raw PCM (Heavy workload for 24/96 target)
- Compressed stream (Larger footprint for the Rpi zero)

I’m looking for direct memory access too, but I can’t find a way to go any further :( Nevertheless, I2s DAC exists, but I can't find a way to connect two Rpis through this.

So I'm looking for recommendations!